# Regular Expression not working in ios11 only working fine in ios10

Tags: regex, react-native, ios10, ios11, nsregularexpression

Requirement;

All Special characters allowed excluding (`) (') () (") and Spaces
using below for the same and working fine in ios 10

```
const UserIdRegExp = /[^`"' \\]$/g;
```

not working in ios11

const value='anand`';

when i am doing UserIdRegExp.test(value);
ios10 return false.

and ios11 return true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 11 Apple introduced "Smart Punctuation", which automatically slants certain punctuation marks based on content.

```
const regex = /[^`"“”'‘’ \\]$/g;
```

Example:

iOS 10: "double quotes", 'single quotes'

iOS 11 (with Smart Punctuation on): “double quotes”, ‘single quotes’

Comment: you are amazing... i spent an hour testing a simple `/^'$/` regex in react native on an iOS device having no idea why it was failing

Comment: @daisura99 Thanks for the appreciation.